# how to pause a loop for a while and do something and again continue in C#?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have while(true) loop which reads QR Code with camera.I want to pause the loop when read a valid QR Code then do something(insert the value in database) and then continue the loop to read other QR Code. I used break and continue but break go out the loop and continue skip my code which i don't want them.I'm working with C# and SQL server.Thanks in advance

---

**Edit**: I don't have any problem with reading Qr Code my code Working properly,I just need to know that how to pause the loop and do something then continue the loop.below is the code. i could to stop the while with if statement

```
while ((int)(1) != 0)
              {
                    ho_Image.Dispose();
                    HOperatorSet.GrabImage(out ho_Image, hv_AcqHandle);

                        HOperatorSet.DispObj(ho_Image, HWindow);
                        operation(ho_Image, hv_Type1, hv_Type2, hv_Num1ecc, hv_Num2qr, hv_Qr, hv_Ecc,
                        HWindow, hv_Timeoutqr, hv_Timeoutecc, out hv_DecodedDataStrings1,
                        out hv_DecodedDataStrings2, out hv_DataCodeHandle1, out hv_DataCodeHandle2,
                        out hv_foundecc, out hv_foundqr);

                        hv_Qr = 0;
                        hv_Ecc = 0;
                        //MessageBox.Show(" QR NuM : " + this.QRNumber);
                        //MessageBox.Show("ECC Number : " + this.ECCNumber);

                        if (this.QRNumber == QRNum && this.ECCNumber == ECCNum)
                        {
                            foreach (string qr in this.QRValue)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(" QR value : " + qr);
                            }

                            foreach (string ecc in this.ECCValue)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("ECC value : " + ecc);
                            }


                        }
              }
```

Comment: Add an Async task, and await, while data are saved into database.

Comment: Have you look at the "yield " usage, I guess it may help you

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but if your code for reading the code is not async, then the other commands won't  be executed until it's done..

Comment: can you please post the code? otherwise the guessing can lead into very wrong directions

Comment: If you just want to pause the loop how about Thread.Sleep ?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a variable that controls when the code is read, check my answer

Comment: "Also i don't share the code because not necessary." interesting approach. Did any of the 3 answers help you?

Comment: @MongZhu below answers are useless. Because i have my own code to read QR Code. I just dealing with pause in loop. i want to try Async,await and yield

Comment: I guess sharing the code would increase the clarity of your question. And people would be able to give you a more precise answer. But that is of course up to you.

Comment: @Mo0rteza None of the below answers is teaching you how to read QR the below answers are teaching you how to pause. Where I put ReadQR(); i commented and said replace it with whatever you have to read the QR and once you read the QR them just set a flag to true and the code will fall into the flag condition and the loop will pause. Give it a try you won't lose anything

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm missing something but this should work:

```
while (true) {
  var data = ReadCode();
  AddToDatabase( data); 

  //catch errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a thing such as pausing a while loop. A  loop can not be paused however, a while loop can be broken, you can exit out of the loop. You can put the whole program on sleep which will "pause" the loop, in fact, the entire program. You can also trap the loop in a block when a condition is met which will also "pause" the loop from continuing whatever it has to do and enter that block finish what it has to finish then carry on with the loop again.

In order to trap it you can use a flag and whenever your condition is met you set the flag to true and you check if that flag is true then do the insertion to database or whatever.
And finally at the end of the loop set back the flag to false.

here is a very simple sample code:

```
bool read = false;
while(true)
{
    //Start reading your QR here or do whatever you want to do; However, make sure that the variable 'read' is set to true when you read the code
    ReadQR();

    //Now check if a code is read
    if(read)
    {
          //Do whatever you want to do here if the code was read such as insertion to database, this technically will pause the loop and finish what's in this block then continue on with the loop, even though I highly recommend breaking your code into methods; for instance don't do the insertion logic here instead put the logic in a method and call it here.

          InsertQRCodeToDb(code);

          //Set the controller variable back to false
          read = false;
    }
}
```

P.S. out of curiosity why are you casting 1 to int? Also why is your condition (int)1!=0?
Can't you just put your condition such as while(true)?  Or while(1) Wouldn't that be a lot simpler and no casting needed?